Sign in with Apple button
So... Whenever you log in for the first time, the user's name is displayed correctly. However, if you kill the app and launch it again, it displays 'Welcome, User,' which is the problem I'm encountering. It should display the user's account name. The func checkUserStatus() is in charge of showing the up to date user's name. I have placed this in .onAppear() so its supposed to display whenever the view appears but it doesn't when you kill the app and launch it again. What do you guys think? Please advise
Disclaimer: The app is linked to CloudKit, and you need an Apple Developer account to run it
    import SwiftUI
    import AuthenticationServices
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State private var viewModel = CloudKitViewModel()
    
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if let user = viewModel.user {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Welcome, \(user.name)")
                       
                        Button(action: {
                            viewModel.signOut()
                        }) {
                            Text("Sign Out")
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 55)
                                .background(Color.red)
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .padding()
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "apple.logo")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        Text("Hello, Sign in with Apple!")
                            .bold()
                                            
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(height: 20)
                        
                        SignInWithAppleButton(.signIn) { request in
                            viewModel.handleAuthorizationAppleIDRequest(request: request)
                        } onCompletion: { result in
                            viewModel.handleAuthorizationAppleIDCompletion(result: result)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 55)
                        .signInWithAppleButtonStyle(.white)
                    }
                }
                
                if viewModel.isLoading {
                    ProgressView("Loading...")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.checkUserStatus()
            }
        }
    }
    
    #Preview {
        ContentView()
    }


//ViewModel and Model

    import SwiftUI
    import CloudKit
    import AuthenticationServices
    
    
    @Observable
    class CloudKitViewModel {
        var user: User?
        var isLoading = false
        var errorMessage: String?
        
        private var container: CKContainer
        private var database: CKDatabase!
        
        init() {
            self.container = CKContainer.default()
            self.database = container.publicCloudDatabase
        }
        
        func checkUserStatus() {
            // Check if user is already authenticated and signed in
            container.fetchUserRecordID { recordID, error in
                if let recordID = recordID {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.user = User(id: recordID.recordName, name: "User")
                        self.fetchUserData(userID: recordID.recordName)
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorMessage = "Failed to fetch user record ID: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        func handleAuthorizationAppleIDRequest(request: ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest) {
            request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        }
        
        func handleAuthorizationAppleIDCompletion(result: Result<ASAuthorization, Error>) {
            switch result {
            case .success(let authorization):
                if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
                    let userID = appleIDCredential.user
                    let fullName = appleIDCredential.fullName?.givenName ?? "User"
                    
                    // Save the user data to CloudKit
                    let newUser = User(id: userID, name: fullName)
                    saveUserData(user: newUser)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.user = newUser
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.errorMessage = "Sign in with Apple failed: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                }
            }
        }
        
        func saveUserData(user: User) {
            let record = CKRecord(recordType: "User")
            record["id"] = user.id as CKRecordValue
            record["name"] = user.name as CKRecordValue
            
            database.save(record) { record, error in
                if let error = error {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorMessage = "Error saving user data: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    }
                } else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("User data saved successfully.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        func fetchUserData(userID: String) {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", userID)
            let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: predicate)
            
            let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
            operation.resultsLimit = 1
            operation.recordMatchedBlock = { recordID, recordResult in
                switch recordResult {
                case .success(let record):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let id = record["id"] as! String
                        let name = record["name"] as! String
                        self.user = User(id: id, name: name)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.errorMessage = "Error fetching user data: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    }
                }
            }
            operation.queryResultBlock = { [weak self] result in
                switch result {
                case .success(_):
                    break 
                case .failure(let error):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.errorMessage = "Error fetching user data: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    }
                }
            }
            database.add(operation)
        }
        
        func signOut() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.user = nil
                    self.errorMessage = nil
                }
            }
    
    }
    
    struct User {
        var id: String
        var name: String
    }


it would be better to move checkUserStatus to the object init, you also need to change @State to @StateObject so it is init at appear. To make that compile you also need to conform the class to ObservableObject (it doesn't matter if you are using @Observable for change tracking instead of @Published).
